# Net in $\mathcal{B}^*$ converging to unbounded functional

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, weak-topology

Let $\varphi$ be an unbounded functional on a Banach space $\mathcal{B}$. Can we always find a net of bounded functionals (i.e. in $\mathcal{B}^*$) converging to $\varphi$ in w*-topology?

Any proof or counterexample?

Comment: Do you have a topology in mind on the space of possibly unbounded functionals?

Comment: Weak*-topology..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $V$ be the directed set of *finite dimensional* subspaces of $\mathcal B$. For each $v\in V$ choose a continuous projection onto $v$ and denote it with $P_v$ (this works with Hahn-Banach and uses that $v$ is finite dimensional). Now define a functional $\varphi_v := \varphi\lvert_{v}\circ P_v$. Note that $P_v$ is continuous and $\varphi\lvert_v$ is a linear functional on a finite dimensional space and as such continuous. Then $\varphi_v$ is continuous.

Now consider $x\in \mathcal B$. If $x\in v$ then $\varphi_v(x) = \varphi(P_v(x))=\varphi(x)$. Now for any $v\in V$ there is a $w\in V$ with $w\supseteq v$ and $x\in w$. Further for any $u\supseteq w$ you have $x\in u$ also. This implies then that
$$\lim_{v\to\mathcal B}\varphi_v(x) = \varphi(x), $$
and $\varphi_v$ converges pointwise to $\varphi$, which is the weak* convergence.